# dynamically adding a class to parent container from a dynamically added container using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a method to dynamically add a container which is attached to the target container . When the action has been performed i removed the action container but now I have to add a class to parent container but problem is it is getting set (class name to parent container ) but it gets removed itself. For more clarification I am adding an sample code

```
<div class="main">
  <ul>
    <li>some contents</li>
    ................
    ................
  </ul>
  <ul class="dynamic_container">
   <li>actions</li>
   ................
  </ul>
</div>
```

dynamic_container is added when user mouseover the main class container and this get removed once action has been executed . But now it gets added(class name) but it gets removed too .
I believe this is basically because $(e.target) get removed ....

Any advice/suggestion will be appreciated . Thanks in advance.

edit :

$(e.target).parents('.main').addClass('current'); (this code does not able to add class to .main div) . This code is executed from ul.dynamic_container (which is added to the dom on mouseover on div.main)

edit 2:
jsfiddle link: this is the structure (not the actual code)

http://jsfiddle.net/CASy6/

Comment: Can't understand what question you're actually asking for help with.

Comment: no errors . Issue with class not getting added to parent container. Updating the question .

Comment: @MattB. there is no js error FYI

Comment: You've given bits and pieces of javascript, but we don't know how it all fits together. It's more likely that we could help if you would create an example of your problem in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: post the whole event handler code...not just small snippet that doesn't work within it. Also why do you say it doesn't work? Could be your css rules aren't specific enough to see changes when the class is applied... demo that replicates problem is always best. Could also be you are expecting `target` to be something it isn't. Can always log `e.target` to console to see what it actually is. Numerous possibilities but is a guessing game without code posted

Comment: @charlietfl thanks! I have already done console log....this class get added but automatically get removed from parent container ...updated my question with jsfiddle link (not the actual code but this is what I was trying to do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for posting the fiddle. Now we can identify some problems that are preventing it from working.

The first problem is that when you try to move the mouse over the buttons, they disappear. If you add some `console.log` statements to the `mouseover` and `mouseout` handler functions, you will see that they get called way too much. This is due to the way these events work in a situation with nested elements.

jQuery provides a good solution to this problem: the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events. Read about them in the [API docs](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/), specifically the section describing the difference between `mouseover` and `mouseenter`.

See this fix implemented in this version of the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CASy6/1/. With this, you can now actually click on the buttons, and also, a whole bunch of unnecessary `.append()` and `.remove()` calls are avoided.

---

The next problem is that no handler is called when you click a button.

The reason for this is that you set up the handlers by calling e.g.

```
$('li.first').on('click', function(e){ ... });
```

when the page loads, but at that moment, the selector `li.first` matches nothing, because you haven't appended the buttons to one of the `div`s yet. So handlers are only attached at page load, and they have nothing to attach to.

One solution for this problem is to use delegated events ([see docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/)). This means we attach a handler to a container element (which is always present, including at page load), and handle events that bubble up from a descendant element.

In this case, we can attach a delegated event handler to the `.main` divs, which handles a click coming from one of the buttons:

```
$('div.main').on('click', 'button.first', function(e){
    $(this).closest('.main').addClass('current');
    alert('first action');
});
```

The second argument `button.first` is a selector which determines which descendant events will be handled by this handler. (I fixed the appended html so the `class` attribute is attached to the `button` element instead of the `li` element; it was inconsistent between the two buttons.)

See these fixes in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/CASy6/2/